# Stuck on white screen at XNA game startup

Tags: c#, windows, xna

When starting an XNA game a white screen flashes very quickly. On slower machines this is more visible than on fast machines. We develop a game suit with a menu system developed in WPF. This menu starts our XNA games and sets its window as the foreground window (only works when it has focus itself)

The problem we have is that if the player keeps pressing the left button after starting the game the system gets stuck in this white screen flash. The screen stays white and the player is unable to exit this screen with the mouse (alt-tab works but is not favored).

How can I prevent this from happening? I do want to set the XNA game as the foreground window, because depending on where the player clicks the menu system could remain active.

This is the code form the menu system that starts the XNA game.

```
var process = Process.Start(info);
var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
while (!process.HasExited)
{
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    if (GetForegroundWindow() == currentProcess.MainWindowHandle)
    {
        Activate(process.MainWindowHandle);
    }
}
```

This is the code that sets the XNA game as the foreground window.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the window to be foreground
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("User32")]
    private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hwnd);

    /// <summary>
    /// Activate or minimize a window
    /// </summary>
    [DllImportAttribute("User32.DLL")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    private const int SW_SHOW = 5;
    private const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;
    private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

    /// <summary>
    /// The GetForegroundWindow function returns a handle to the foreground window.
    /// </summary>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    private static void Activate(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        ShowWindow(windowHandle, SW_RESTORE);
        SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle);
    }
```

Thanks,
Wouter

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all the flash is probably due to the DirectX device initialization that happens when the XNA window is restored from minimization or when the device is initially created; there are events that can capture these events. I don't know what are you doing when pressing the left key, but I would check to make sure that you are not causing another device initialization to happen.

Key events are the ones contained in [GraphicsDeviceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphicsdevicemanager_members.aspx), especially the resetting events. Make sure that when the device is resetting, no input is handled.